# Does a web-component that ships server side logic cease to be a web-component?

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

The definition says the use of any or all of the 4 standards hugging the platform itself, makes a web component.

- custom-element
- shadow-dom
- imports
- templates

As an author, sometimes, I may have to work around some shortcomings / rather unsupported requirements, to get things cracking

for example, an HTML import is still not widely accepted and even when it is, it doesn't do foreign imports.

Even if that happens, Any external stylesheet is not strictly scoped.

and a `<link rel=import type=css...>` still has no traction

> If I need to then scope an external stylesheet, I need to first localize it, do an html import and not `type=css` and then , I would have the scoped stylesheet within my element

I'd want a component, that'd not expect a developer integrating it to his site, do anything but install it.
the component would do an async fetch request to the php logic, which would wrap any external library as html and respond to the fetch

If I author a component then, with some server side logic say php, to CURL the foreign resource , and place a document on the origin that can be a local import to be scoped,

would it cease to be a web-component?

Is the deifnition strictly front-end only?

Comment: The gist is more of can I package a web component I authored, along with an 

accompanying php file that acts as the server side api endpoint for the web component to call on,

and can I publish it under web components, even though it has a single php file accompanying the package

I really do not mean I want to author a web component with php or anything to such effect

Comment: You can do that, but that doesn't make any sense - what if I want to use python or ruby or golang or whatever instead of your PHP file?
Document what the component does and make it customizable enough, let your users handle server side logic for themselves - it should not be components concern.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing things - you can't "author a component with server side logic" by definition - since components are just some sugar JS running in the browser.
You can however make your component fetch resources from server side using fetch api/ajax - it will still be a component. If you want it to be reusable by other you just need to make sure you gave enough configuration options.

As for the external CSS sheets, you can normally style your application, the trick is to have your "view components"(non-reusable components only related to your application business logic), not use shadow dom - then you can style your views and components normally. Alternatively you can create one big "shared-styles" file that your components include.

Answer (score 0):

It would not be a "Web Component" in the sense Google defined it, and in the sense of the Stack Overflow `web-component` tag.

Anyway, it seems that the term "Web Components" is [not officially used any more](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/NOTE-components-intro-20140724/) for a few years, maybe because the technologies it recovers are not at the same level of maturity and adoption in concurrent web browser, or maybe because the term was too generic (and then often used for client-sid e technologies like React or Angular).

**Update**

Of course you can design some custom elements that perfom server requests (Ajax-like, REST calls) to get some data or any other parameters that will affect their behaviour or rendering.

You can load exernal stylesheet in Shadow DOM with the `@import url` CSS rule.

Comment: Well thats not entirely true. It´s still called Web Components. But now this is more like a collection of standards but yes what was ment to be WebComponents is now known as Custom Elements. Also this collection contains the HTML Import and Shadow Dom And these 3 are known as WebComponents. Also these are all client side standards. More Information can be found here: https://www.w3.org/wiki/WebComponents/ here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements  here: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/customelements

Comment: That's what I've said. They used to be knonw as Web Components, but now this term is not used any more in any *official* publication. It's only a generic term for promotion (moreover without capital letter).

Answer (score -2):

so on my opinion Web Components can´t contain any server side logic. Let´s say a Component just renders Text and your Server puts this text into your component before he sends it to your client. 
I´d say thats a bad idea since the component will be chached by your Browser and next time your client uses this component it will use the cached verison and will still contain the old text. Better would be to use ajax to load the content and keep your Component stateless. 
On the other hand as you mention in your post sometimes it is necessary to use such machanisms to get around the shortcoming of Polymer. For instance importing a external css/js library wich wasn´t ment to import into polymer. In this case I use gulp to create importable files for polymer, not sure if this is considered bad habbit.